# JSF page element cannot trigger method from backing bean with action attribute.(JSF2.0 + primefaces)

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a primefaces dock nav bar with a menuitem element, that should trigger the logout mechanism of my web app, but it doesnt work, i dont know why. Can someone help me find the reason why the logout funccion is not called when i click on the menu item?

This is the element at the JSF page template:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dock position="top">
    <p:menuitem value="Logout" icon="unsecuredimages/logout.png" action="securityController.logOut()" rendered ="#{!securityController.checkLogged}"/>

    </p:dock>   
</h:form>
```

This is the backing bean where the logOut() Method is located:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SecurityController {

...

public String logOut() {
        authentificationEJB.releaseUserState();     
        return "main.xhtml";
    }

...
```

And this is the EJB that accesses the session and releases it from the logged user:

```
@Stateful(name = "ejbs/AuthentificationEJB")
public class AuthentificationEJB implements IAuthentificationEJB {
...
// Logout
    public void releaseUserState() {
        // 1-Check if there is something saved in the session(or wherever the
        // state is saved)
        if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getSessionMap().isEmpty()) {
            // 2-If 1 then flush it
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().release();
        }       
    }
    ...
    }
```

When i click on the menuItem i get this exception:

> WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces
>   Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service()
>   for servlet Faces Servlet threw
>   exception
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException   at
>   com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.assertNotReleased(FacesContextImpl.java:639)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.getCurrentPhaseId(FacesContextImpl.java:515)
>     at
>   javax.faces.event.ExceptionQueuedEventContext.(ExceptionQueuedEventContext.java:148)
>     at
>   javax.faces.event.ExceptionQueuedEventContext.(ExceptionQueuedEventContext.java:101)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.queueException(Phase.java:156)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.queueException(Phase.java:149)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:109)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>     at
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
>     at
>   filters.RestrictPageFilter.doFilter(RestrictPageFilter.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
>     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

**Update**

```
<p:menuitem value="Logout" icon="unsecuredimages/logout.png" action="#{securityController.logOut}" rendered ="#{!securityController.checkLogged}"/>

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class SecurityController {

    @EJB
    private IAuthentificationEJB authentificationEJB;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String notificationValue;



    public String logOut() {
         HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
            if (session != null) {
                session.invalidate();
            }
        return "main.xhtml";
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you need the `release()` method. I think this method is the reason for your exception. A quote from the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#release%28%29):

> After release() is called on a
>   FacesContext instance (until the
>   FacesContext instance has been
>   recycled by the implementation for
>   re-use), calling any other methods
>   will cause an IllegalStateException to
>   be thrown.
>
> ...
>
> The implementation must call
>   setCurrentInstance(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)
>   passing null to remove the association
>   between this thread and this dead
>   FacesContext instance.

I use the following logout method. Maybe this is helpful for you:

```
public String logout() {
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        session.invalidate();
    }
    user = null; // reset user
    // optional: addSuccessMessage

    return "login";
}
```

Comment: I modified my code at the managed bean(update above) to look like yours, now i don't see the exception. I manually navigate to other pages and it looks like session is correctly invalidated.It works fine, just i don't get redirect to main.xhtml why?

Answer (score -1):

Try changing from RequestScoped to for example Sessions, I've had some trouble in the apst with RequestScoped backing beans.

Comment: When i put sessionScoped i cant run the app, it says:

`org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: WELD-000072 Managed bean declaring a passivating scope must be passivation capable.`

Comment: When i use ViewScoped i can build but i have the same exception. What other options do i have? That managed bean should not be applicationScopped